# Cannot read property 'store' of undefined in Javascript class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I wrote a small convenience class to centralize all of the email validation we do across our app.

However, when I run this, I get a console error:

> Cannot read property 'store' of undefined

I'm clearly missing an import here but unclear as to how I'd import `store`. My gut tells me I'm doing something wrong here. Getting back into web after doing mobile for the last four years so I'm a little rusty :)

Thanks

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { checkEmail } from 'app/auth/redux/actions.js';

class EmailValidator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // via: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13178771/602210
    this.regex = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$/i;
  }

  // Tests whether the email is in a valid format like name@example.com
  emailIsValid(email) {
    return this.regex.test(email);
  }

  * loginEmailExists(email) {
    const { emailIsTaken } = yield this.props.checkEmail(email);
    return emailIsTaken;
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    checkEmail: (email) => dispatch(checkEmail(email)),
  };
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(EmailValidator);
```

And then the implementation in another component:

```
import EmailValidator from 'app/helpers/EmailValidator';
```

lower in the component, in a function:

```
const validator = new EmailValidator();
if (!validator.emailIsValid(email)) { ... } // throws error below
```

Full error

```
connectAdvanced.js:123 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of undefined
    at new Connect (connectAdvanced.js:123)
    at eval (index.js:149)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:149)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:199)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:256)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:270)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:561)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:583)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:680)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:688)
Connect(EmailValidator) @ connectAdvanced.js:123
(anonymous) @ index.js:149
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:149
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:199
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:256
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:270
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:561
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:583
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:680
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:688
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:662
runEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:816
runExtractedEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:824
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:4826
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:20233
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2151
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4905
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:20284
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:255
interactiveUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:20283
interactiveUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2170
dispatchInteractiveEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4882

react-dom.development.js:289 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of undefined
    at new Connect (connectAdvanced.js:123)
    at eval (index.js:149)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:149)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:199)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:256)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:270)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:561)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:583)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:680)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:688)
```

Comment: I don't see any property `store` in this part of the code, where/what is it supposed to be?

Comment: I assumed I didn't need to explicitly import `store`, that I could use `connect` and `dispatch` to dispatch my actions appropriately but I could be wrong here.

Comment: When I have `loginEmailExists` uncommented as well as `mapDispatchToProps` and `export default connect...`, I get the `store` error in my console. When they're commented out, I don't get that error. So it's something there...

Comment: Please show the error

Comment: I added it to the original post. Thanks

Comment: All application should be wrapped with Provider with store property set. It looks like it hasn't been done here.

Comment: Component doesn't extends React.Component. Where is render() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you have setup the store correctly, or even have set it up at all. But here's an example of how you might do it:

```
// src/store.js
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducer from './reducers'

const enhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() // Redux DevTools, a must

const store = createStore(reducer, enhancer)

export default store
```

```
// src/index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import store from './store'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />   
    </Provider>

, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Keep in mind to extend your classes with `React.Component`, e.g.:

```
import React from 'react';
...
class EmailValidator extends React.Component {
...
```

Hope this gets you on the right track. Your dispatch and connect syntax is fine, so that is not the issue at least.

Comment: Thanks Yannick, I've updated my original post. I have a `store` that's long been working. I've just been trying to get this component going. Not sure what's up from here

Answer (score 0):

`store` can't be imported - it needs to be provided with `<Provider/>`

Make simple redux project running first.

Did you ever worked with redux?

You can't `connect` redux store to any class, it's a HOC - component enhancer.

Your `EmailValidator` can be a HOC, too.

Comment: This is a class I'm adding to an existing react project that works and has a `Provider`, sagas, etc. Yes I've worked with redux, I've just never tried to implement this kind of a helper class. Can you give me an idea of how to refactor my class to make this work correctly?

Comment: HOC's are described in [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), many HOCs can be `compose`d (f.e. recompose project), you can create a hook ...